# TSQL Openquery with Text Field hangs up MS SqlServer

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, openquery

This happens when I query a text field using linked server.  For example: select * from openquery(LS,'select text_field from table')

then my server blows up!  HELP?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blows up"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information you provided.

Probably, one or both of the servers are busy, the table is very large and the link between them is slow.

What happens if you run the query directly on the remote server?